# How to template by-value returning value and by-const-ref returning const ref

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Is there a way to have those two cases as a single template:

```
// accepts by-value, returns value
int f(bool cond, int a, int b) {
    return cond ? a : b;
}

// accepts by-const-ref, returns const ref
const std::string& f(bool cond, const std::string& a,
                     const std::string& b) {
    return cond ? a : b;
}
```

Using at least C++11.

Comment: only those two types exactly, or were these two examples of a more general case?  And if so, in which cases do you want by-value and which by-const-ref ?

Comment: the `const T&` should already work for `int`.

Comment: it may return a temporary `const int&` but the problem also exist for the `string` version

Answer (score 0):

Possible, but call would similar to `f<int>(42, 51)`; (using stuff like [boost's call_traits](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/utility/doc/html/utility/utilities/call_traits.html)).

A simplified version might be

```
template <typename T>
struct call_traits
{
    using type = const T&;
};

template <typename T>
using call_traits_t = typename call_traits<T>::type;

template <>
struct call_traits<int>
{
    using type = int;
};

// T is not deducible from call_traits_t<T> (aka call_traits<T>::type)
template <typename T>
call_traits_t<T> f(bool cond, call_traits_t<T> true_value, call_traits_t<T> false_value)
{
    return cond ? true_value : false_value;
}
```